# Angular 2: Pass Service to Class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service that gets some data from an API and returns an object which has a key of value `Company[]`, it looks like this:

```
getCompanies(){
    return this.authHttp.get(this._companiesUrl)
        .map(res => {
            let response = res.json() || [];
                response.items = response.items.map(thing => new Company(thing) );
                return response;
            });
}
```

My `company.model.ts` looks like this:

```
export class Company{

id: number;
....
constructor(obj:any){
    ....
}

// I'd like to be able to do this:
changeName(newName: string){
    this.companyService.changeName(this.id, newName).sub....
}
```

In my company model I'd like to have some methods that would change the `Company` object's property and communicate this changes with the server.

I'm struggle to understand how to pass the `CompanyService` Injectable into the `Company` class, especially since new companies will almost exclusively be created in the `CompanyService` itself.

Please let me know if I can provide further clarification or code.

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you want to change the name of your company? Altering the name inside the model and pushing it to your backend should NOT be done inside your model.

Comment: @Deutro I'd like to change it inside the model and on the backend... If it shouldn't be done in the model should it be done in a component that imports a service?

Comment: I guess I did not formulate it correctly. It is fine to change the property of your model inside your model. But the call to the backend should not be done inside the model. The companyService.changeName() method should be called from inside a component.

Comment: @Deutro thanks, that's good to know. In which case I might as well cast the JSON using an interface and forget the model (no need for methods if I'm only doing property changes...)

Answer (score 1):

If you provide `CompanyService` in your `app.module` you will have one instance of it to use throughout your application.

In `app.module.ts`:

```
import { CompanyService } from 'whereEverThisFileIs'
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [..., CompanyService],
  ...
})
```

To get it inside `Company` you would do this:

```
import { CompanyService } from 'whereEverThisFileIs'

export class Company{
  id: number;
....
constructor(obj:any, private _companyService: CompanyService){
....
}

changeName(newName: string){
  this._companyService.changeName(this.id, newName).sub....
}
```

Angular will inject the instance of `CompanyService` from the root for you

You can read about this here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#angular-dependency-injection